# ERD Table and Field Questions

Tags: sql-server

![ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxQKT.png)

My question is two-fold.

First, this is my first design and I am using the Mere Mortals book to help me.  He states, *"...each table represents a single, specific subject."*  So should I combine the `Statistics` table and `Designer` tables into the `Project` table since the subject is Project?

Secondly, the two fields of `WhyClientChoseUs` and `ClientLossReason` are opposed to one another and only one of these two fields would be filled out. Is that OK?  And should this go in the `Project` table and not the `Client` table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the annotations in your ERD diagram, I understand that:

1. A `Client` may have many `Projects`
2. A `Project` may have many `Designers`

If that is true, then these 2 tables should not be consolidated.

Likewise, depending on your definition of `WhyClientChoseUs` and `ClientLossReason`, there are reasons to keep both.  (E.g. you may have a reason `WhyClientChoseUs` and later need to add the `ClientLossReason`.  Not uncommon on big projects.)

But, because the client may continue with one project but abandon another, the `Project` may be a better place to keep that information.

But answers to these kinds of question do depend on your definitions.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I decided after carefully re-reading the Mere Mortals part on Null values that ClientLossReason and WhyClientChoseUs are either/or and therefore, should allow null values